# Calculating each factor level's sd() for a variable

Tags: r, purrr, standard-deviation, factors, levels

I have been asked by my coauthor to add `sd` to the factor variables that have more than two levels, and `sd(as.numeric(df$factor))` is giving me a single output instead of the sd for each. I imagine `purrr::map` could handle it but df%>% select(factor) %>% as.numeric %>% map(~(sd(.))) outputs an error `Error in function_list[[i]](value) :  'list' object cannot be coerced to type 'double'` even though df is not a list.

Comment: `sd` for each means each column?  The `sd` will return a single value for a column,  If you need to get `sd` for each level.  then you need `df %>% group_by(factor) %>% summarise(SD = sd(yourcolumn))`

Comment: You didn't specified the context, but i think you should be careful about taking the sd of a categorical variable. For example: there is no sense in taking the sd of a variable like `c(1,2,1,1,3,2,3,3,1)`, where 1 represents the color blue, 2 red, and 3 green, there is no underlying scale for you to see "2 (red) as twice as much as 1 (blue)".

Comment: Please add data using `dput` or something that we can copy and use. Also show expected output for the data shared. Read about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 1):

If it is the `sd` for each `level` of the `factor` column, we need to use that as a grouping variable

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
    group_by(factor) %>%
     summarise(SD = sd(anothercolumn, na.rm = TRUE))
```

---

Based on the description, if we need the `sd` of `factor` variables having more than two levels

```
df %>%
     summarise(across(where(~ is.factor(.) && nlevels(.) >2),
         ~ sd(as.numeric(.))))
```